# php variable in header

Tags: php, variables, url, header

Age old question.  I have tried everything I can think of included multiple searches on this site.

My example URL is mydomain.com/login.php?aircraft_id=3542

```
$aircraft_id = $_GET['aircraft_id'];
echo $aircraft_id;   //This works fine to verify the $_GET is working
```

... bunch of login code to verify user
... if password verified:

```
 session_start()
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
 header('Location: test.php?aircraft_id=' . $aircraft_id);
```

I can not get this variable to pass to the next page for the life of me.

I have tried

```
 header('Location: test.php?aircraft_id=' . $aircraft_id);

 header("Location: test.php?aircraft_id=$aircraft_id");
```

as well as other forms of single quote / double quotes.

The $_GET is working as I can echo the $aircraft_id on the login page but once I submit, the header will not capture the variable to pass on to the next page.

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
        </div>    
        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
        </div>
        <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
    </form>
```

Comment: Form submissions are usually POST not GET.

Comment: Show us the form

Comment: Do you get redirected to `test.php?aircraft_id=`? If so, your variable declaration is wrong, it's probably `$_POST[]`

Comment: Also, what does the value of `$aircraft_id` look like?

Comment: I have tried $_GET and $_POST.

Comment: Yes, I get redirected to the test.php?aircraft_id=

Comment: Not sure if it'll solve the problem, but you're missing a space `name="username"class="form-control"` between `"username"` and `class=`, it may not be reading the name right due to this syntax error

Comment: @Spence Does the aircraft id contain spaces or special characters?

Comment: I corrected that ... the form, login, verification, header redirect works fine if I don't use the variable I am trying to pass.

Comment: aircraft_id is only a number that correlates to a database entry id.     
Example: test.php?aircraft_id=3445

Comment: @Spence I don't see an `aircraft_id` in your form, it's part of your URL on the submission page? Submitting your form is probably getting rid of your id

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton ... BINGO!  Thank you!  That was it.  I feel stupid.  I added a hidden input to the form with the $_GET['aircraft_id'] in the value and it works.  Thanks so much for the quick diagnosis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` gets rid of your GET parameters in your URL. There are a few ways to fix this:

## Add a Hidden Field to Your Form

```
<input type="hidden" name="aircraft_id" value="<?=$_GET['aircraft_id'];?>"/>
```

## Alter Your `action` Call

```
action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>?aircraft_id=<?=$_GET['aircraft_id'];?>"
```

## Remove Your `action` Call

You could also simply remove `action=""` from your form, and it should also fix the issue. Forms by default will post to the same page they are on given they have no `action` instruction.

Comment: Yes ... that was it.  This is the exact fix I tried.  Thank you!!

Comment: @Spence Added some alternatives. Keep in mind you should mark answers as "accepted" if they've helped you solve your problem.

Comment: Wish I could upvote ... I am new to this site.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Spence You may not be able to upvote, but accepting the answer will earn us both a little bit of reputation, but only accept answers that have actually helped you. :) EDIT: Thanks!

Comment: Done! Thank you!